# 2006 DTS rear suspension

Tags: suspension, cadillac, rear

I have a 2006 DTS and the rear suspension rides very bumpy. If I push on the rear of the car it only goes down an inch or two before stopping. What’s the matter?

Answer (score 1):

One of two things is going on with your DTS. Since it has air bags in the back, either one of the bags has ruptured or the air compressor has quit working. An airbag is pretty straightforward, as it's just replacement. The compressor on the other hand, may not be. It could be that the fuse/relay which runs the compressor has blown. Or the compressor itself may have given up the ghost.